# How should i solve this problem when appveyor build my blogs reports some errors?

Tags: continuous-integration, appveyor

Use appveyor to build a project which could auto deploy my blog. My blog source code is deployed in GitHub repo. When i use appveyor to build this project , some errors occur.

I have checked my profile and environment about username and email, it's right. And i didn't find password profile in appveyor environment!

The following is the content of appveyor.yml:

> secure is right , to protect my privacy, i did't show it

```
clone_depth: 5

environment:
  access_token:
    secure: ptnWH+BWFZ8LLx0mKP+YEYOBCz56B36sNBh/GBSethxcVGMhwXrU/A8W+MEFB+Q5

install:
  - node --version
  - npm --version
  - npm install
  - npm install hexo-cli -g

build_script:
  - hexo generate

artifacts:
  - path: public

on_success:
  - git config --global credential.helper store
  - ps: Add-Content "$env:USERPROFILE\.git-credentials" "https://$($env:access_token):x-oauth-basic@github.com`n"
  - git config --global user.email "%GIT_USER_EMAIL%"
  - git config --global user.name "%GIT_USER_NAME%"
  - git clone --depth 5 -q --branch=%TARGET_BRANCH% %STATIC_SITE_REPO% %TEMP%\static-site
  - cd %TEMP%\static-site
  - del * /f /q
  - for /d %%p IN (*) do rmdir "%%p" /s /q
  - SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion & robocopy "%APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER%\public" "%TEMP%\static-site" /e & IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 1 (exit 0) ELSE (IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 3 (exit 0) ELSE (exit 1))
  - git add -A
  - if "%APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH%"=="master" if not defined APPVEYOR_PULL_REQUEST_NUMBER (git diff --quiet --exit-code --cached || git commit -m "Update Static Site" && git push origin %TARGET_BRANCH% && appveyor AddMessage "Static Site Updated")
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know where in the build the errors are occurring. A link to the build might help as well.